# .msi downloading as text

Tags: internet-explorer, tomcat, windows-installer

I'm using tomcat 6.0 and struts2.

When I try to click on a link to download a .msi file on IE, the page loads up text from the .msi file instead.

Has anyone encountered this before? What can be done?

Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another guru told me to add this to tomcat/conf/web.xml:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>msi</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-msi</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

And that works :)

Comment: Does this work if you add mime types to the application web.xml ? I don't want to change the default one in Tomcat itself.

Answer (score 0):

AddType application/octet-stream .msi  in Tomcat

Comment: where do you add that? I saw the .htaccess solution, but not sure where to place it? Do I have to restart Tomcat?